# How to slidedown the div when (page loaded and condition fulfill)

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

Below is my sample code. i want to load loading.jsp. The div default is not slide down.

When the `<%=msg%>` is not empty. then the div wll slide down.

Flow: `loading.jsp -> servlet (detect error) -> loading.jsp (div slide down)`

```
$("#errorLoading").load(function() {
        if(<%=msg%> != ""){
                $('#errorLoading').slideDown('slow');
        }
});
<div class="alert alert-error" id="errorLoading" name="errorLoading">
<%=msg%>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me about this.

Comment: if you get your answers, do you accept those?

Comment: the error message that in div

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this to slide down/up div tags](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-slideup-slidedown-and-slidetoggle-example/)

Answer (score 0):

See `you have to use $.trim function of jquery` to check `if div is filled with the message` you are printing in that. then check that in a condition and just slide your desired div.

***Note: div has to be hidden first.***

fiddle you can find :

> **http://jsfiddle.net/wZ6Br/**

```
you can check with putting some dummy text there.

 var divErr = $.trim($('.alert-error').text());


 if (divErr) {
     $('#errorLoading').slideDown('slow');
 }
```

Comment: did you check the fiddle link?